# Sort Hash Tables Glib - qsort

Tags: c, sorting, glib

I'm trying to sort a GLib hash table by id that looks something like:

```
key - id
    {
    "Red",     2,
    "BLue",    4,
    "Yellow",  5,
    "Orange",  8
    }
```

I'm just not sure how to approach this because [GLib](http://library.gnome.org/devel/glib/unstable/glib-Hash-Tables.html) does not have a sort method. I was thinking to use qsort or GCompareFunc

Any ideas will be appreciate it!

Comment: GCompareFunc is not a sort method - it's a standard function prototype for comparison functions to be provided to sort methods. (And as SB noted, GLib does have sort methods, for the types which it makes sense to sort.)

Answer (score 4):

Hash tables aren't supposed to be sorted.  You should get a GList* from the g_hash_table_get_keys (or values if that's what you're sorting) and sort that.  Also, be careful about confusing [glibc](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/) and GLib.